# Using sweetalert after PHP redirect

Tags: php, sweetalert

I want to use a sweetalert after a bad login. Not working.. Do I use correct CDN?

login.php

```
if(password_verify($passwordInput, $dbPasswd)) {
    header('Location: ../store.php');
} else {
    header('Location: ../index.php?login=false'); //redirect to index.php and show sweetalert
}
```

index.php:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>
if(isset($_GET['login']) == 'false') {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
        swal({
           title: "Your title",
           text: "whatever",
           type: "error"
        });
     });</script>';
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm you get inside if(isset($_GET['login']) == 'false' when login fails?

Comment: if i use a simple javascript alert(''), it works..

Comment: @AngelDeykov in console i got this error: `Uncaught (in promise) SweetAlert: You can only use SweetAlert AFTER the DOM has loaded!`

Comment: aaaaa then use $(document).ready(function() { ....}) to wrap your code with

Comment: Ill edit my answer now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223706/discussion-between-darkfelcore-and-angel-deykov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use sweet alert with this syntax, usually when making ajax requests. Here is example:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "PATCH",
                url: "myurl.php",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Success',
                        text: 'whatever',
                        type: 'success'
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, error) {
                    swal({
                        title: xhr.responseJSON.title,
                        text: xhr.responseJSON.detail,
                        type: 'error'
                    });
                }
            });
```

So in your case you should have something like:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['login']) == 'false') {
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       swal({
          title: 'Your title',
          text: 'whatever',
          type: 'error'
       });
    });
  </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I gforgot to include my JQuery file :/